# Return back to application

Tags: android, android-intent

I have an application which works like Facebook Messenger. I can tray it and there is a small icon in the side of the screen which suppose to open the application.

I'm looking for a way to open my application without refreshing the whole Intent. I need a way to show the application as it was before the user trayed it.

1. User enters the application.
2. Starting a service of the tray icon.
3. App minimized (click the home button). tray apperas in the top left side of the screen.
4. Access another app and click the tray icon.
5. The tray icon should bring my application back to the main screen.

Currently, it bring the application back, but refresing my intent and all the values and texts I typed in my EditTexts are no longer there. It happens because I create a new intent:

```
 Intent it = new Intent(this,MainActivity.class)
                    .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity(it);
```

so how I can resume my app without overwriting the current intent?

Comment: Then save content of Edit somewhere in onPause and restore it in onResume

Comment: Thats nice idea but I thought that there is another simpler way since I have 5-6 edittexts. thanks.